# Is this sentence grammatically correct , 'There is nothing like Australia'

Tags: grammar

I know that it's an object and you can use it may be like that but I thought when you are referring to a country you more faith as a culture and I am not sure if it can be used in the context 'there is nothing like Australia' may be a better fit

Comment: Australia is not an object, It is a location, So you may say: "There is nowhere like Australia".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. There's a idiom:

[There's nothing like (something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there%27s+nothing+like)

It is said about something you enjoy immensely.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid, it won't be common to say like that.

The safest use could be...

> There is *no country* like Australia

This speaks everything you want! Australia is a country and then you are comparing the rest of the countries with it and then calling Australia as unmatched.